# Theory of algorithms and counting the number of operations

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, genetic-algorithm, theory

If 100 assignment operations m=n are performed in 1 second, then how many operations n^2 and 2^n will be performed in a second?

It seems to me that it is necessary to perform an operation that is the reverse of the necessary ones. That is, extract the root and get the logarithm

Comment: Impossible to say. How much time does exponentiation or multiplication or addition take?

Comment: If this question is related to time complexity of programs (i.e. Big O), then if n operations take 1 second, n^2 operations will in general take n^2 seconds and 2^n operations will take 2^n seconds.  I say in general, since the unknowns in this example include the time to load the data, time to setup the environment, and the time to display results, which in the case of your example may or not require the bulk of the timing. As @trincot stated, it is really not possible to say with any specificity.